# Storing data on "cloud"

Tags: java, android

I am creating an App that stores tasks. What would be a good way to store each task data on a cloud? I was thinking of using the free space google drive provides. Is that possible?

Anything besides hosting my own server will be best. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use http://aws.amazon.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Google Cloud Storage free quota. I recently migrated some apps to the cloud and the results are awesome. If your app grows really big, the pricing is still low and you can always get to consume the free quota they provide. Besides that, the api is well documented and there are plenty of tutorials.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you should use Google Drive to store data at Google Clouds . please check and started with below link for cloud storage .

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16457039/selecting-picture-from-sdcard-and-store-it-to-google-drive). This is about storing image to `Google drive` but you can store any type of file by using `MIME type */*`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the Dropbox Sync API. The Sync API takes care of syncing all your data with Dropbox through a familiar, file system-like interface. It's like giving your app its own, private Dropbox client.

> Reference :https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android